# If / Else in Google Docs Forms

Tags: if-statement, google-docs, survey

I´m actually trying to create a new survey and wonder if there is a possibility to add something like IF/Else.

So, if the user push the Radio-Button "no" it pops up a new field with something like "why you don´t push yes". But the field is only shown, when you pushed no in the question before.

I would be gratefull about some answers.

greetz jmoe

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of "Go to page based on answer":

[image]

In Page 2 you would make a paragraph field:

[image]

Here's the [form in action](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1DNlXO89N1qLbt0390YMmfGyKsaCHe6SWJz7Sd8UTv6g/viewform)

Comment: Thanks for the Info. But I still see the Paragraph field all the time, don´t I?

Comment: Nope: you only see it if you answer "no". See the first screenshot -- if you answer "yes" -- it redirects you to the page number 3.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. But it´s not possibly to do it on the same page with an invsibile box or something, or?